# How can I prevent IE from opening supported text or image file types directly in the browser window

Tags: internet-explorer, download, mime-types

I have a web application that uses a browser redirect to open a resource and I would like to have the native application open the resource (image or text file) instead of the file rendering directly within the browser.

The server is running IIS 7.5 and the client is Windows 7 running IE 9 or 10. Note that I have already ensured that file/program associations within the browser are not set to Internet Explorer.
For example, the .txt file extension should be opening with Notepad versus IE. This seems like a relatively simple request although I cannot find any reference on how to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more complicated than most people imagine due to support for MIME Handlers in IE.

In most cases, you can get the behavior you want by sending a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=whatever.dat` response header.

If you'd like, you can also suppress the **Open** button using the `X-Download-Options` directive, introduced in IE8 to control visibility of the "Open" button on the file download dialog.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx. This directive is currently only supported in IE8+. This header partially obsoletes existing "DownloadOptions" META tag introduced in IE6: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533689(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree that it is more complicated that expected. In my case I am doing a response redirect on the client so the HTTP GET request is from the client directly to IIS so I do not have an option to set the Content-Disposition header. Is this the only way possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand-- why can't you have IIS send the header?

Comment: Typically the header would be set in the code behind such as Response.Headers.Add however in my case the redirect is to the file directly under IIS. Of course it's possible to have IIS add a response header for every request but it needs to be unique for each file request.

Comment: As far as I know, IIS offers the ability to add custom headers to files under a particular application or path. If not, you'd need to build a simple proxy page like ReturnFileWithCDA.aspx?filename=foo.txt.

Comment: It definitely sounds like the solution would be to use the proxy page. However, in my case this is not possible since it is a VB6 IIS Web application which does not have streaming capability. However, your response is correct and valid and will indeed work with ASP.NET. I will therefore mark your answer as accepted. Thank you.